# OpenGL ES 2.0 - memory management in drawing lines (graphing)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I finally got some functioning code to draw lines (in Xamarin/monotouch)

```
        //init calls
        Context = new EAGLContext (EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2);
        DrawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat.Format24;
        EAGLContext.SetCurrentContext (Context);

        effect = new GLKBaseEffect ();
        effect.UseConstantColor = true;
        effect.ConstantColor = new Vector4 (1f, 1f, 1f, 1f); //white
        GL.ClearColor (0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);//black


    public void DrawLine(float[] pts) {
        //generate, bind, init
        GL.GenBuffers (1, out vertexBuffer);
        GL.BindBuffer (BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertexBuffer);
        GL.BufferData (BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr) (pts.Length * sizeof (float)), pts, BufferUsage.DynamicDraw);

        // RENDER //
        effect.PrepareToDraw ();
        //describe what's going to happen
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray ((int) GLKVertexAttrib.Position);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer ((int) GLKVertexAttrib.Position, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
        GL.DrawArrays (BeginMode.LineStrip, 0, pts.Length/2);
    }
```

I have a couple questions.

1. Is this approach for drawing lines optimal?  Are there any suggested improvements (i.e. antialiasing, etc..)

   ```
       GL.Clear (ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
       effect.ConstantColor = new Vector4 (1f, 1f, 1f, 1f); 
       DrawLine (line);
       effect.ConstantColor = new Vector4 (1f, 0f, 1f, 1f); 
       DrawLine (line2);
   ```
2. Does all the memory associated with the line disappear  when I call GL.Clear()?  i.e. do I have to do any memory cleanup, or can I just keep calling GL.Clear() followed by DrawLine() and not worry about memory management?
3. I'm planning on using these functions for graphing.  If the underlying data changes (but I have the same number of lines, is there a subset of functions that I can call to more efficiently update the lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL.GenBuffers (1, out vertexBuffer)` creates a buffer on the GPU and has to be deleted after the usage. In most cases you create buffer to push data to GPU which will not be updated frequently and are used to draw those data many times. There is probably a flag to stream the data (instead of `DynamicDraw`) for constant updating though. You could use that to reuse the same buffer but it would probably be best to just push the data pointer directly from the CPU: Lose all 3 lines concerning the buffer and insert `pts` into `VertexAttribPointer` instead of 0 for the last argument.

You say you will be using this for graph drawing. If the graph data will not be modified every frame and you can compute all the points you still might want to benefit from buffers. Instead of trying to push every line to its own buffer try pushing all the lines to a single buffer (even axis can be there). Use `GL.DrawArrays (BeginMode.LineStrip, 0, pts.Length/2)` to draw specific lines as last 2 arguments control the range in current buffer to draw (to draw 5th line only you would write `GL.DrawArrays(BeginMode.LineStrip, 5*2, 2)`). So when the graph data should update; delete the current buffer, create a new buffer, push the data to buffer, bind the buffer, set the vertex pointer and then just keep calling the draw method.

GLClear has nothing to do with memory cleanup at all. It will only clear (set values) the buffers attached to your frame buffer, in your case it will set all the pixels in your render buffer to the color you set in ClearColor. Nothing more. Other common cases are to also clear depth buffer, stencil buffer...

As for all the optimization and anti-aliasing it all depends on what you are doing, there is no general answer. Though if your scene gets too edgy try to search around for multisampling.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm receiving data constantly and have a configurable timer that initiates a redraw.  I don't expect any redraws that will draw the same data. Otherwise, excellent advice that i had not found in looking at tons of documents online.  though i started going through the docs on developer.apple, and they seem better than any other tutorials or books that i've looked at..